# Conditional line break

Tags: javascript

I only want to line break if variable var is not a null value, how would I go about this?

```
<div>
{var && `${var}`} <br />
{var2 && `${var2}`}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using this in pure JavaScript or in React. 

The tag suggested you are using this in pure JavaScript, But in case you are using this in React, Then we can use it directly either by ternary operator or directly using logical operator. I dont' think you require `${}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other conditional element

```
<div>
  {var && `${var}`}
  {var && <br />}
  {var2 && `${var2}`}
</div>
```

Or shorter,

```
<div>
  {var && <>{`${var}`}<br /></>}
  {var2 && `${var2}`}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only checking for `null`

```
{var !== null ? '<br />' : ''}
```

If any falsy statement is the condition you want to check (undefined , null , NaN , 0 , "" , and false)

```
{var ? '<br />' : ''}
```

Comment: This looks like a React question. This would insert the text `"<br />"` rather than an actual element

Answer (score 0):

You are creating HTML in JavaScript, so I assume you have used back-ticks around opening and closing `div` first. Then based on the value of `var`, You want to set the break point.

First thing is `var` is a keyword in Javascript and should not be used as the variable name.

Second is we can do something like this using **ES6 back-ticks** and **interpolation.**

```js
    let myVaribale = 23; // Not Null
    const htmlTest = `<div>
          <span>Testing the line-break</span>
          ${myVaribale && `<br/>` }
          <p> Life is a test</p>
    </div>`;

document.body.innerHTML = htmlTest;
```

```html
<html>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
{var ? '<br />': ''}
```